# Why gold electrodes are used if an adhesion layer is required?

Tags: electronics

Gold electrodes are useful to make good ohmic contact to high work-function materials. However, deposition of few-nanometer Cr, Ti or Ni adhesion layer is typically required prior to gold deposition.

Since a different metal (not gold) – the adhesion layer – is in direct contact with the target material, what's the point of depositing gold on top of the adhesion layer? Why not just make a single metal electrode out of the adhesion layer material?

(Work functions: Au 5.1 eV, Ni 5.04-5.35 eV, Cr 4.6 eV, Ti 4.33 eV)

Comment: Cr, Ti, and Ni are there to eat any oxide/nitride/carbide crud. The gold is to make a nice metallic path. Further, those three metals are much harder to wire bond to than Au. Further yet, they will keep reacting over time and during, e.g., packaging.

Comment: @JonCuster what do you mean by "nice metallic path"?

Comment: It may do that as well, but the work function won't match if there is an intermediate layer. The adhesion layer is quite thin, and tends to end up dispersed in the near-interface region. Without it you will get a Schottky barrier, not an ohmic contact.

Comment: @JonCuster but Cr/Ti adhesion layer  has a significantly different workfunction compared to Au.

Comment: So does an oxide layer! The Cr and Ti break it up, and allow the Au to be in direct contact with the real substrate.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm not sure what you mean. In particular, I was referring to electrode-semiconductor interface.